# How to identify a count index in Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, iaas

I want to deploy multiple resources in Azure with Terraform, I'm using the count index to specify how many resources I want but I would like to deploy some extra disks in one VM but it gives me errors when I tried to execute it

My configuration looks like this

```
# Create a virtual machines 
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  count                 = 2
  name                  = element(var.vm_names_grupo1,count.index)
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [element(azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.id, count.index)]
  vm_size               = element(var.vm_size_grupo1,count.index)

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = element(var.vm_osdisk_name_grupo1,count.index)
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    disk_size_gb      = element(var.vm_osdisk_size_grupo1,count.index)
  }

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = element(var.image_reference_publisher,count.index)
    offer     = element(var.vm_image_offer,count.index)
    sku       = element(var.sku,count.index)
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = element(var.vm_names_grupo1,count.index)
    admin_username = var.admin_username
    admin_password = var.admin_password
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "example" {
  count                = length(var.extradisks)  
  name                 = element(var.extradisks,count.index)
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = 10
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "example" {
  count              = 2  
  managed_disk_id    = element(azurerm_managed_disk.example.*.id, count.index)
  virtual_machine_id = "vmPrueba1"
  lun                = "10"
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
}
```

The problem is in this line `virtual_machine_id = element(azurerm_network_interface.nic.1.id, count.index)` I don't know how to specify a vm

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Also there is no such line in your code: `virtual_machine_id = element(azurerm_network_interface.nic.1.id, count.index)`? So why would it be problematic?